# AuthenticatorException: bind failure on AVD

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to create an Android App that uses Google's OAuth library, [like this sample](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/tasks-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/tasks/android/TasksSample.java?repo=samples).

However, when I make a call to getAuthTokenByFeatures I get an exception that prints this out on LogCat:

```
05-24 10:56:58.224: W/System.err(557): android.accounts.AuthenticatorException: bind failure
05-24 10:56:58.236: W/System.err(557):  at android.accounts.AccountManager.convertErrorToException(AccountManager.java:1563)
05-24 10:56:58.236: W/System.err(557):  at android.accounts.AccountManager.access$400(AccountManager.java:140)
05-24 10:56:58.236: W/System.err(557):  at android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask$Response.onError(AccountManager.java:1409)
05-24 10:56:58.236: W/System.err(557):  at android.accounts.IAccountManagerResponse$Stub.onTransact(IAccountManagerResponse.java:69)
05-24 10:56:58.236: W/System.err(557):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:338)
05-24 10:56:58.236: W/System.err(557):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

However, this does not happen with an actual Android device. I'm emulating Android 4.0.3 and could not for the life of me find an answer to this anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: You'd need the account authenticator for Google installed for the account manager service to be able to bind to it. All "Google experience" phones (i.e. most) will come with this authenticator shipped - the SDK however - not so much.

Comment: I see, thanks. Can you tell me how to get around this? I just noticed that there's an option under Dev Tools called Google Login that isn't working either.

Comment: @JSFernandes - I did run my app on emulator with google api's (2.3.3) as u did but still getting same error. Any idea whats wrong or what else can I do? also same thing happening on actual device. Do I need to login into Google account on device?

Answer (score 6):

This is usually seen when you don't declare the Authenticator in the manifest. See [Creating a Stub Authenticator](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-authenticator.html#DeclareAuthenticator).

```
<service
        android:name="com.example.android.syncadapter.AuthenticatorService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
        android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
</service>
```

Comment: .. or when you declare in the manifest outside of the <application></application> manifest container, as I did since 1 hour... F.