# android.accounts.AuthenticatorException: bind failure

Tags: android

I am getting the following exception; I know its not much to go on, but there seems little to no working documentation out there. Suffice it to say, I have tried all the examples on implementing my own Authenticator.

I have found a proposed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736245/authenticatorexception-bind-failure-on-avd) to fix my Manifest-File (declaring the service). Had already done that, problem persisting.

My initial solution is based on [this example: write-your-own-android-authenticator](http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/)

```
W/System.err﹕ android.accounts.AuthenticatorException: bind failure

W/System.err﹕ at Android.accounts.AccountManager.convertErrorToException(AccountManager.java:2024)

W/System.err﹕ at android.accounts.AccountManager.access$400(AccountManager.java:144)

W/System.err﹕ at android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask$Response.onError(AccountManager.java:1867)

W/System.err﹕ at android.accounts.IAccountManagerResponse$Stub.onTransact(IAccountManagerResponse.java:69)

W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the same situation. Searched everywhere but no luck. There are actually very few resources and tutorials for android `authenticator`. I also referred the same article [udinic:write your own android authenticator](http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/).

It's not so detailed and its easy to get lost. I actually changed my `accountType` in `authenticator.xml` and forgot to change in `AccountGeneral` class.
Both should be same, otherwise you activity won't bind to `AuthenticatorService` for callbacks.

*`authenticator.xml`*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><account-authenticator 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="your_account_type_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_navigate_before"
    android:smallIcon="@drawable/ic_navigate_before"
    android:label="@string/label"
    android:accountPreferences="@xml/prefs"/>
```

*`AccountGeneral.java`*

public class AccountGeneral {

```
/**
 * Account type id
 */
public static final String ACCOUNT_TYPE = "your_account_type_name";

/**
 * Account name
 */
public static final String ACCOUNT_NAME = "your_account_name";

/**
 * Auth token types
 */
public static final String AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_READ_ONLY = "Read only";
public static final String AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_READ_ONLY_LABEL = "Read only access to an FitDodo account";

public static final String AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS = "Full access";
public static final String AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS_LABEL = "Full access to an FitDodo account";

public static final ServerAuthenticate sServerAuthenticate = new ParseComServerAuthenticate();
```

}

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: AccountGeneral class and authenticator.xml both file have same name but bind failure error as it is

Comment: You sir, are a boss! Saved me a lot of trouble.

Comment: Dammnn nice catch. that one was hidden AF! Thanks for posting!!!

Answer (score 0):

You will also get this error if you forget to add the `<service> ...</service>` block in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
 <service android:name=".auth.YourAuthenticationService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
            android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
    </service>
```