# Android AccountManager throws AuthenticatorException: bind failure when adding account

Tags: java, android, android-service, accountmanager, android-authenticator

I am trying to add custom account with `AccountManager.addAccount()` on android. I was following [this tutorial](http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/). When I am trying to get result with `AccountManagerCallback`'s `run` method I get `AuthenticatorException` with message: `android.accounts.AuthenticatorException: bind failure`.

After some research I found two potential solutions, but I already [declared authenticator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736245/authenticatorexception-bind-failure-on-avd) inside `application` tag, and [checked my account type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035888/bind-failure-accountauthenticatorservice-on-android). I also compared manifest permissions with those from tutorial. I am using android studio 1.4, and I tried it on several emulators, and on physical device.

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`, and also `authenticator.xml` and `account_preferences.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.myproject" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/test_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".view.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".view.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.test.myproject.model.utility.MyAuthenticatorService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
                android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

I have also tried naming service `.model.utility.MyAuthenticatorService` with no effect.

authenticator.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:accountType="com.test.myproject"
        android:icon="@drawable/test_logo"
        android:smallIcon="@drawable/test_logo"
        android:label="@string/not_implemented"
        android:accountPreferences="@xml/account_preferences"
        />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

account_preferences.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/not_implemented" />
    <CheckBoxPreference android:title="Use debug server"
        android:key="isDebug"
        android:summary="Connecting to a debug server instead of prod server"/>
    <SwitchPreference android:title="Debug Logs" android:key="logsVerbose" android:summary="Show debug logs on LogCat"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Here is `MyAuthenticatorService`:

```
public class MyAuthenticatorService extends Service {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        MyAuthenticator myAuthenticator = new MyAuthenticator(this);
        return myAuthenticator.getIBinder();
    }
}
```

Here is `MyAuthenticator`:

```
public class MyAuthenticator extends AbstractAccountAuthenticator {

    private Context context;

    public MyAuthenticator(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle addAccount(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String accountType, String authTokenType, String[] requiredFeatures, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(LoginActivity.ARG_ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType);
        intent.putExtra(LoginActivity.ARG_AUTH_TYPE, authTokenType);
        intent.putExtra(LoginActivity.ARG_IS_ADDING_NEW_ACCOUNT, true);
        intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, response);
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, intent);
        return bundle;
    }
   //other override methods (they all return null for now)
}
```

And here is `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private AccountManager accountManager;
    private static final String ACCOUNT_TYPE = "com.test.myproject";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);

        this.accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);

        signIn(ACCOUNT_TYPE, "access_token");

        //other stuff

    }

    private void signIn(String accountType, String authTokenType) {

        final AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future = accountManager.addAccount(ACCOUNT_TYPE, authTokenType, null, null, this, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
            @Override
            public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
                try {
                    Bundle bnd = future.getResult();
                    showMessage("Account was created");
                    Log.d("udinic", "AddNewAccount Bundle is " + bnd);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    showMessage(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }, null);
    }
}
```

When debbuging, error is thrown on `Bundle bnd = future.getResult();`, and future has state 3 and outcome `android.accounts.AuthenticatorException: bind failure`. Tough execution never gets to LoginActivity, or at least breakpoints are not triggered, here it is:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AccountAuthenticatorActivity {

    public final static String ARG_ACCOUNT_TYPE = "ACCOUNT_TYPE";
    public final static String ARG_ACCOUNT_NAME = "AUTH_TYPE";
    public final static String ARG_AUTH_TYPE = "ACCOUNT_NAME";
    public final static String PARAM_USER_PASS = "USER_PASS";

    private AccountManager accountManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        this.accountManager = AccountManager.get(getBaseContext());


    }

    public void login(View view) {
        EditText usernameEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textLoginUsername);
        EditText passwordEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textLoginPassword);

        String ownerUsername = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
        String ownerPassword = passwordEditText.getText().toString();
        String clientId = "test";
        String clientSecret = "test";

        AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(this);

        TokenRequestTask tokenRequestTask = new TokenRequestTask();
        tokenRequestTask.execute(ownerUsername, ownerPassword, clientId, clientSecret);
    }

    private class TokenRequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Intent> {
        @Override
        protected Intent doInBackground(String... params) {

            final String accountType = getIntent().getStringExtra(ARG_ACCOUNT_TYPE);

            String ownerUsername = params[0];
            String ownerSecret = params[1];
            String clientId = params[2];
            String clientSecret = params[3];

            String authToken = signIn(clientId, clientSecret, ownerUsername, ownerSecret, "password");

            Bundle resultData = new Bundle();
            resultData.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, ownerUsername);
            resultData.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType);
            resultData.putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, authToken);
            resultData.putString(PARAM_USER_PASS, ownerSecret);


            final Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
            resultIntent.putExtras(resultData);
            return resultIntent;
        }
    }

    private String signIn(String clientId, String clientSecret, String ownerUsername, String ownerSecret, String grantType) {
        MyApi20ServiceImpl service = (MyApi20ServiceImpl)new ServiceBuilder().provider(MyApi20.class)
                .apiKey(clientId)
                .apiSecret(clientSecret)
                .signatureType(SignatureType.QueryString)
                .build();
        Token token = service.getAccessToken(ownerUsername, ownerSecret, grantType);
        return token.getToken();
    }
}
```

Here is complete stack trace:

```
10-19 10:39:05.042 25931-25931/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
10-19 10:39:05.042 25931-25931/? I/art: Late-enabling JIT
10-19 10:39:05.068 25931-25931/? I/art: JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
10-19 10:39:05.118 25931-25931/com.test.myproject W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.test.myproject-1/lib/x86
10-19 10:39:05.355 25931-25960/com.test.myproject D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
10-19 10:39:05.358 25931-25931/com.test.myproject D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xad974e50, tid 25931
10-19 10:39:05.366 25931-25931/com.test.myproject W/System.err: android.accounts.AuthenticatorException: bind failure
10-19 10:39:05.366 25931-25931/com.test.myproject W/System.err:     at android.accounts.AccountManager.convertErrorToException(AccountManager.java:2147)
10-19 10:39:05.366 25931-25931/com.test.myproject W/System.err:     at android.accounts.AccountManager.-wrap0(AccountManager.java)
10-19 10:39:05.366 25931-25931/com.test.myproject W/System.err:     at android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask$Response.onError(AccountManager.java:1990)
10-19 10:39:05.366 25931-25931/com.test.myproject W/System.err:     at android.accounts.IAccountManagerResponse$Stub.onTransact(IAccountManagerResponse.java:69)
10-19 10:39:05.366 25931-25931/com.test.myproject W/System.err:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
10-19 10:39:05.423 25931-25960/com.test.myproject D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xac17e080, tid 25960
10-19 10:39:05.433 25931-25960/com.test.myproject I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-19 10:39:05.538 25931-25960/com.test.myproject W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-19 10:39:05.538 25931-25960/com.test.myproject W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaf125cc0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
10-19 10:39:05.903 25931-25931/com.test.myproject I/Choreographer: Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-19 10:39:05.975 25931-25960/com.test.myproject W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-19 10:39:05.975 25931-25960/com.test.myproject W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb3fe0c40, error=EGL_SUCCESS
10-19 10:39:07.392 25931-25960/com.test.myproject E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xac027c50
```

Can someone help me with resolving this issue?

Comment: Have you tried changing the name of your service in manifest to: 
.model.utility.MyAuthenticatorService

Comment: I have, same thing happens

Comment: And added exported="false" to the service?

Comment: false and true, on different emulators and physical device, no effect, also tried all permutations with service name

Comment: Could you print the complete stack trace?

Comment: of course, I have edited question

Comment: And add the Login activity code where you actually add the account

Comment: Will do in few hours when I get back to my computer, but execution never actually gets to LoginActivity or at least, breakpoints I put there are never triggered, that's why I didn't put it in a first place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so, it was really a copy paste error, it made me crazy. In `authenticator.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:accountType="com.test.myproject"
        android:icon="@drawable/test_logo"
        android:smallIcon="@drawable/test_logo"
        android:label="@string/not_implemented"
        android:accountPreferences="@xml/account_preferences"
        />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

`</PreferenceScreen>` is not supposed to be here.

If you are getting this error, check your xml files.

Answer (score 1):

You can using addAccountExplicitly

Comment: Well, it's not exactly what I am looking for, It's more of a workaround in this situtation I would like to use `addAccount`, instead of `addAccountExplicitly`. 

However I did try it, and I got exception `java.lang.SecurityException: uid 10053 cannot explicitly add accounts of type: com.test.myproject`, but I did not put any more effort into it since it's not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue too.

Just like Miljac's, my problem was about `AndroidManifest.xml` file.